# Grab DB values and display For Each - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Having a bit of trouble getting my `For Each` function to display all the values from a DB into a view. Where am I going wrong? Not a back-end pro, nor did I write it. Database table is extremely simple, one column named `id`. I want to display each of the rows in my for each.

I have a custom `MY_Controller.php` file and in the `_construct` I have this, which fills in variables globally across the site.

```
$this->country_zones = $this->Studios_model->get_studios();
```

Model:

```
function get_studios()
{
    //this will alphabetize them
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'ASC');

    $query  = $this->db->get('gc_studio_zones');

    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $countries = $row->id;
    }
    return $countries;
}
```

In my view:

```
<?php foreach($this->$country_zones as $country):?>
    <li><?php echo $country['countries']->id;?></li>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Error:

```
Cannot access empty property...etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a typo in your view regarding your loop variable, it should be `this->country_zones`:

```
<?php foreach($this->country_zones as $country):?>
    <li><?php echo $country->id;?></a></li>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Besides, your Model isn't returning an array, but only the last id. You need to push the values to your result array:

```
function get_studios()
{
    //this will alphabetize them
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'ASC');

    $query  = $this->db->get('gc_studio_zones');

    $countries = array();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $countries[] = $row;
    }
    return $countries;
}
```

Comment: Good eye...now I have another error: `Severity: Warning 
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: This worked when I removed `->id` from the echo in the `<li>`. However, only the first character is being displayed for each value...?

Comment: @MikeBarwick Well, because you only store the id in the results array of your model function. I updated the answer, now every returned row is saved. This means that the view has to be modified as well with the values you want to show there (currently it'll output only `id` again).

Comment: Confused. So everything in your answer should work? It doesn't...gives this error: `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in...etc`

Comment: And what I meant by only shows the first character. For example, in Column "id" I have one row with the value, "Canada". When this value was pulled into the view, only the character "C" was shown.

Comment: Well, now you need to access the properties in the view like you normally access them in CodeIgniter. Updated again.

Comment: Cheers! Works. I'm a front-end guy, still trying to grasp the whole back-end thing.Thanks!! :)